# Disable NotifyIconOverflowWindow autohide

Tags: c#, winapi, taskbar, flyout

I have done flyout window similar to win7 battery meter. It is behaving just like built in one except when it is shown via notify icon who is located on `NotifyAreaOverflowWindow` aka notify overfow area that window autohides itself after some time while it should hide only when my flyout closes. The only difference that I could spot with `spyxx` that after some time overflow window simply sends itself an `WM_SHOWWINDOW wp:0 lp:0` message.

How can I prevent the overflow window from autohiding while my flyout is active?

[image: screenshot]

- Image 1: Test flyout shown after click on notify icon which is located on overflow area + couple seconds of user inactivity.
- Image 2: Battery meter flyout shown by clicking on notify icon which is located in overflow area + 2 mins of user inactivity.

Comment: The down voter did not provide any comments, but I think you should put more effort in your question. Tips : use line feeds and add a screen shot of what you want to avoid, some code, etc.

Comment: I can't post any pictures or edit text better (tryed) because this all is sent from phone. About code, it can be faund as shell sample called NotificationIcon in Windows SDK 7.1 .

Comment: [That sample is in C++](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/shellintegration). Did you rewrite it in C# or is your question mis-tagged ? +The window in that sample hides itself when it is inactive. Do you click anywhere or the windows just hides itself after some time ?

Comment: Try to move it's icon to notify oferflow area and click on it. Wait. After some time overflow area will hide and the window will just hang there. I need for overflow window not to hide while the flyout is shown.

Comment: The notification area is the user's property; other than placing your application in it or removing that application, you don't get to interface with it. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/26/10157902.aspx

Comment: I can't post int in question so I'll post it here. Image 1 : Test flyout shown after click on notify icon which is located on overflow area + couple seconds of user inactivity. Image 2: Battery meter flyout shown by clicking on notify icon which is located in overflow area + 2 mins of user inactiviti.
postimg.org/image/tgaw2f6f1/2bfb96dd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call

```
NotifyWinEvent(EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPSTART, Handle, OBJID_CLIENT, 0);
```

before you show your window and call

```
NotifyWinEvent(EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPEND, Handle, OBJID_CLIENT, 0);
```

after you hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Flyouts are no different from any other window.

If I'm understanding your problem, which is that the windows disappear over time, then the solution is quite simple.  Do not use whatever `NotifyAreaOverflowWindow` is.  Instead, create your own window, with the appropriate properties (no control box, no max/min buttons, no title text, etc...).  Because it's likely out of your control to set the duration of the class/object you're using.  It's likely designed for single-notifications, and not something moderately useful ;).

Plus, you'll be able to do fancy things as desired without running into anymore issues.

The following tutorial goes in great lengths on how to position it so perfectly:
http://blog.quppa.net/2010/12/09/windows-7-style-notification-area-applications-in-wpf-part-3-taskbar-position/

Comment: Thank for your response. NotifyAreaOverflowWindow is that window (shown near number 2 on second picture) refered as notification area overflow in this document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511448.aspx. I do not use it directly I just wan it to remain visible as long my own flyout is.

Comment: My answer remains unchanged.  I'm suggesting you just create your own window so you have proper control.  See the link I provided.